# Book/Notes recommendation for self studying Frame Theory

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, operator-theory, book-recommendation

I'm a student who has had one course in Functional Analysis. Next semester I'm planning to attend some lectures on Completely bounded frames.I would like to do a self study of some frame theory so that I can be better prepared to understand lectures on completely bounded frames.Could someone recommend some good books/notes/video lectures to start working on this?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know if next reference is about the theory in which you are interested, because I know bit about this. Choose *Sections* in this [web of the Notices of the AMS](http://www.ams.org/journals/notices) as *What Is...* and choose (see down) the paper *WHAT IS... a Frame?* by Christopher Heil (thus the full reference for this paper is NOTICES of the AMS, Volume 60, Number 6, June/July 2013). I like these kind of papers by the quality and since are a good introduction to new notions and theories. Good luck with your question and course. Is not required a response.

Comment: Dear @user243301,Thank you. I'll surely have a look!

Answer (score 0):

For the basics of theory of frames, one may refer to the article 'The Art of Frame Theory' by P.G. Casazza. The books for frame theory are
1. An introduction to frames and Riesz bases by O. Christensen
2. Frames for undergraduates by Han and Larson.
The details of these can be found on internet.
Hope it is helpful.